# php page not updating

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the MySQL error when I run it:

```
1972-11-08AlfredLibrejaCorallesLakeShore140 Rosal Street Loma Biñan Laguna
Notice: Undefined index: myfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\taugamma\update_member.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: idd in C:\xampp\htdocs\taugamma\update_member.php on line 14
Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 12
```

and here is my code:
update_member.php

```
$bd1 = $_POST['bd1'];
$bd2 = $_POST['bd2'];
$bd3 = $_POST['bd3'];
echo $bd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($bd1 . '-' . $bd2 . '-' . $bd3));
echo $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fname']);
echo $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lname']);
echo $mname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['shadow']);
echo $mchapter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pob']);
echo $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
echo $photo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['myfile']['name']);
echo $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['idd']);

    $query = "UPDATE
            tblmembers
          SET
            firstName     = '" . $fname . "', 
            lastName      = '" . $lname . "', 
            middleName    = '" . $mname . "', 
            birthday      = '" . $bd . "', 
            motherChapter = '" . $mchapter . "', 
            address       = '" . $address . "', 
            photo         = '" . $photo . "'
          WHERE
            ID  =  " . $id . "'";
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        echo 'Error' . mysqli_error($con);
    }else{
header("Location: show_all.php");
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

here is my code in HTML or form, 
update.html

```
<form action="update_member.php" method="post">
                <table border="0" width="100%" height="1400px">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" width="15%" style="background-color: #191919;"></td>
                        <td colspan="4" height="5%" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #191919; color: #FFF056;">
                        <span>Update Member Data</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['ided'] ?>" name="idd" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Firstname:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['fName'] ?>" onkeydown="return alphaOnly(event)" name="fname"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Lastname:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['lName'] ?>" onkeydown="return alphaOnly(event)" name="lname"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Middlename:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;
                        <input type="text" onkeydown="return alphaOnly(event)" value="<?php echo $_POST['mName'] ?>" id="shadow" name="shadow">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Birthday:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" maxlength="4" size="3" name="bd1" id="bd1" value="<?php echo $_POST['bd1'] ?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"> / <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['bd2'] ?>" size="1" name="bd2" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"> / <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['bd3'] ?>" maxlength="2" size="1" name="bd3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"> yyyy / mm / dd
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%" style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Mother Chapter:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="pob" value="<?php echo $_POST['mChapter'] ?>" onkeydown="return alphaOnly(event)"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;" width="10%"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['address'] ?>" name="address"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;" width="10%"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">I.D. No.:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['idNum'] ?>" name="idnum"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                        </td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;" width="10%"></td>
                        <td height="3%" class="labels">Photo:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td width="10%" height="3%" style="background-color: 191919;"></td>
                        <td style="background-color: 191919;">

                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" style="background-color: 191919;">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" onclick="showFileName()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="7"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
```

It directly goes to show_all.php and doesnt give any errors, but it make no any changes. :(

Comment: Any errors u r getting ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty The errors are at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Which line is line 13?

Comment: @Barmar, No they are not, there is a big different between `Notices` and `Errors`. `Notices` can be ignored by explicit command or php setting.

Comment: now i found the error, but when it run, it makes any changes. but it does not give any errors. @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: @user3204815 What does your form look like? In other words, the HTML.

Comment: @OrelEraki The Mysql error is there, too. It begins with "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: @Barmar, I know. But i wrote you that the first messages are not errors, Just the last one.

Comment: @OrelEraki So both the notices AND the error are at the beginning of the question. Notices are also relevant, the notice about `idd` almost certainly explains why the database isn't updating after he fixed the quote problem.

Comment: @Barmar, Notices aren't relevant he wrote "php page not updating" and not "php page throw lots of messages". The lack of update is driven from the `MySQL` error and not the `Notices` the parser is throwing.

Comment: See his comments below some of the answers, he said he fixed the quote problem and the database is still not updating. That's because he's not setting the `$id` variable properly, and the notice about `idd` being an undefined index explains that.

Comment: I only expiriencing one error, it is only on the photo.

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing the quote around `$id`:

```
WHERE
    ID  =  " . $id . "'";
```

In other words, it should be:

```
WHERE
    ID = '" . $id . "'";
```

Comment: That explains the MySQL error, but not the PHP undefined index errors.

Comment: My wild guess on that one would be that there's a mismatch in what you see in the form versus the expectation on the server side.

Comment: It still doesnt updating. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your header redirect will never work as you're outputting (using echo), before changing the header location.

So you will either:

```
if(!mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        echo 'Error' . mysqli_error($con); // print your error to the screen
} else{
    header("Location: show_all.php"); // do nothing as you've already echo'd further up the script
}
```

Comment: I think the output is all for debugging, so it's just as well that it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Might explain what he means by not working though ;-)

Comment: In some of the comments he said that it's not updating the DB. The redirect has nothing to do with that.

Comment: here is the output:

Notice: Undefined index: myfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\taugamma\update_member.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: idd in C:\xampp\htdocs\taugamma\update_member.php on line 1

Answer (score 0):

the main error comes from this

```
  $_POST['idd']
```

and

```
  $_FILES['myfile']
```

fix that idd where it comes from, and even if you fix the query , you will get the error from that variable $id and $photo.

and your query should be like that

```
  WHERE
        ID  =  '" . $id . "' ";

               ^---you missed single quote here
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the FIRST notice:
Make sure that you are posting a file under a form field called: "myfile".

```
echo $photo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['myfile']['name']);
```

if the file (photo) is optional, you can do:

echo $photo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (isset($_FILES['myfile'])? $_FILES['myfile']['name']: "");

To fix the SECOND notice:
Make sure that the real name of the post variable is "idd"

```
echo $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['idd']);
```

And, remove the ' on this line

```
 ID  =  " . $id . "'";
```